# where does the _() underscore syntax in Typo ERB files come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm seeing an underscore syntax in the Type ERB files e.g. <%= _("Uploads") %> that I don't recognize - does anyone know what the library is that supports this - is it referring to partials or something ...?

https://github.com/fdv/typo/

Comment: I can't speak for Ruby, but in most other languages that's the localization function for gettext.

Comment: As say @deceze it propably is an alias to `t` method which is alias to `I18n.translate` helper.

Comment: sounds like a good guess - many thanks - I found some docs, but still no mention of the mapping to the underscore thing ... http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: Sometimes, I can find where a method is defined by passing in less or more arguments, for example, `_(1,2,3,4)`. It will result in an exception and you will find where the method is defined in backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have said, it is indeed the localisation function.

It is [this](https://github.com/fdv/typo/tree/master/vendor/plugins/localization) plugin in Typo and you can see the actual method declaration [here](https://github.com/fdv/typo/blob/master/vendor/plugins/localization/lib/localization.rb).